# How to change color of "fa icon" when mouse over on it?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I want to change the color of two fa icons which is placed in the stack. But the color is not changed for outer icon.

HTML:

```
  <span class="fa-stack fa-5x">
    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-home fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
   </span>
```

CSS:

```
  .fa-home:hover{
    color: yellow;
   }

  .fa-circle:hover{
   color: white;
   }
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rajagopalx/k3c1c0bf/

Comment: It does indeed change the colour but the `home` icon is in front of it and covers it. This leads to the `hover` state of the `circle` never being triggered and it not changing color therefore.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the hover on the surrounding element:

```
.fa-stack:hover .fa-home {
    color: yellow;
}   
.fa-stack:hover .fa-circle {
    color: white;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bnh84trn/

Comment: I didn't see your answer 'til after writing mine up... +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

If you change the way your css is written and target the `fa-stack` on hover it works great.

CSS:

```
.fa-stack:hover .fa-home {
  color: yellow;
}
.fa-stack:hover .fa-circle
{
  color: white;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/p2yLcsw0/2/

Answer (score 1):

You can use hover on the wrapping element.  The .fa-circle is not technically hovered, because it is hidden by the home.

This will work with any generic icon, not just home:

```
.fa-stack:hover .fa {
    color: yellow;
}
.fa-stack:hover .fa-circle{
    color: white;
}
```